# Regular expression to match word starting with Aa to Ch

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular expression to match words that starting with "aa" to "ch". So far, I was able to do from "a" to "c" without being case sensitive, but was not able to go further:

```
\b([a-cA-C]|\d+)
```

The idea is to select last name starting with AA to CH. Exemples :

- Match : Aaron
- Match : Chub
- No Match : Celtic

It is not used in any particular programming language. It is actually to use in a CRM that accepts regular expression as conditions to trigger certain actions.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does the range include e.g. `Az` or do you mean simply `[A-C][a-h]`? Or what do you mean by range?

Comment: Also, you need to [edit] your question to indicate which programming language, editor, or other tool you are targeting. See the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for details.

Comment: Don't use regex just write the code.  Why are you going to introduce an extra complexity to your project that you don't understand.  Think about the other developers working on the project at the time, if they have to come a cross it and edit it.

Comment: Adding examples in comments is not helpful, I'm afraid. You use a term "range" in a way which isn't well-defined; you need to explain it. Your question needs to be complete and self-contained.

Comment: Sorry, first question here. Still learning. ^^

Comment: Then, what about `Bbcadad` or `CGblah`. Do they match or not? Edit the question and give real examples of the words you think should match and a couple that do not match. Again: what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions

Range aa to ch is

aa to az, ba to bz, ca to ch

Match is case insensitive

Regex for Perl / PCRE engine:

```
/^(?i:[ab][a-z]|c[a-h])/
```

This matches any string starting with an `a,b or c` if it starts with an `a` or `b` the second letter can be `a to z` if it starts with `c` the second letter can be `a` to `h`

Comment: Thank you! I understand the idea, but it does not work in the app. Unfortunately, the first name and the last name are used in the same field (our CRM is completly flawed). How would you modify the regex so it scans only the second and + word ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way to skip the the first word. I use this Regex

```
\b(?i:\s[ab][a-z]|\sc[a-h])
```

This way, it matches any word starting with a blank space (\s) avoiding the first word which is usually the first name.